# how best to manage manage members and roles in a .NET application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, authentication, webforms, asp.net-authorization

I realise this question probably doesn't suit the Q&A format of SO, though I figured this is by far the best community to provide some insight into this. What is the difference between Forms Authentication, MembershipProvider, SimpleMemberShipProvider and Sessions when it comes to tackling authorisation and authentication?

I won't ask "which is better" as that would obviously depend on the purpose of its implementation. I am of the understanding that managing this data through sessions is generally not applicable for this, though the list I provided most likely is not an exhaustive one.

I am unsure as to the benefits and limitations of each and how best to implement them. Ideally I would be making a web forms application using VB.NET but am fine with C# and MVC as well.

Any help or online resources that can clear this up would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I'd do some reading about ASP.NET Identity
http://www.asp.net/identity

It's the newest and most feature-rich ASP.NET membership infrastructure.

The Identity site also provides some background into the older types of membership here:
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity